# Show only a maximum of items in a GridView

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

is there an easy way to show only a maximum size of items. For example I have a list with 20 items but in my GridView I want to show only 9. Is it possible? I have testet MaximumRowsOrColumns but that has no effect.

Thanx 
newone

Comment: Does your collection need to change dynamically?

Comment: no it is only loaded once

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work

```
public IEnumerable<Object> Items
{
    get 
    {
        return _items.Take(9);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a XAML answer? Or could I only realize it this way?

Comment: You may be able to come up with a solution using behaviors. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj682995(v=vs.105).aspx